# NVD3 Discrete BarChart With Json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to put a json file into a NVD3 barchart, but I'm not able to do what I want. I don't know much of JS, but trying to learn for a final project at school, so please help =]

Heres the code I got from an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="../src/nv.d3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<style>

body {   overflow-y:scroll; }

text {   font: 12px sans-serif; }

svg {   display: block; }

#chart1 svg{   height: 500px;   min-width: 100px;   min-height: 100px; /*   margin: 10px;   Minimum height and width is a good idea to prevent negative SVG dimensions...   For example width should be =< margin.left + margin.right + 1,   of course 1 pixel for the entire chart would not be very useful, BUT should not have errors
*/ }

</style> <body>

  <div id="chart1">
    <svg></svg>   </div>

<script src="../lib/d3.v3.js"></script> <script src="../nv.d3.js"></script> <!-- including all the components so I don't have to minify every time I test in development --> <script src="../src/tooltip.js"></script> <script src="../src/utils.js"></script> <script src="../src/models/axis.js"></script> <script src="../src/models/discreteBar.js"></script> <script src="../src/models/discreteBarChart.js"></script> <script>





historicalBarChart = [    {
    key: "Cumulative Return",
    values: [
      { 
        "label" : "A" ,
        "value" : 29.765957771107
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "B" , 
        "value" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "C" , 
        "value" : 32.807804682612
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "D" , 
        "value" : 196.45946739256
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "E" ,
        "value" : 0.19434030906893
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "F" , 
        "value" : 98.079782601442
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "G" , 
        "value" : 13.925743130903
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "H" , 
        "value" : 5.1387322875705
      }
    ]   } ];




nv.addGraph(function() {     var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
      .x(function(d) { return d.label })
      .y(function(d) { return d.value })
      .staggerLabels(true)
      //.staggerLabels(historicalBarChart[0].values.length > 8)
      .tooltips(false)
      .showValues(true)
      .transitionDuration(250)
      ;

  d3.select('#chart1 svg')
      .datum(historicalBarChart)
      .call(chart);

  nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

  return chart; });


</script>
```

My problem is here:

```
historicalBarChart = [ 
  {
    key: "Cumulative Return",
    values: [
      { 
        "label" : "A" ,
        "value" : 29.765957771107
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "B" , 
        "value" : 0
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "C" , 
        "value" : 32.807804682612
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "D" , 
        "value" : 196.45946739256
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "E" ,
        "value" : 0.19434030906893
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "F" , 
        "value" : 98.079782601442
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "G" , 
        "value" : 13.925743130903
      } , 
      { 
        "label" : "H" , 
        "value" : 5.1387322875705
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to put my Json values there, how can I do that?

Here is my Json file, one if for the X, and other for the Y axis:

X Axis:

{"periodos":["112","121","122","131","132","141"]}

Y Axis:

{"reprovados":["247","164","250","147","144","0"]}

If someone could please answer me as complete as possible I'd be very thankful =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about what kind of graph you need since you say you want the values in diferent dimensions. I created a chart with all data in the same dimension ... I guess you will be able to fulfill your needs with it.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fafix/5/edit)

```
var json1 = {"periodos":["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]};
var json2 = {"reprovados":["20","0","32.81","396.46","0.19","98.08","13.93","5.14","15.14"]};

var data = [{values: []}];
for(var i = 0; i < json1.periodos.length; i++){
  data[0].values.push({
    label: json1.periodos[i],
    value: Number(json2.reprovados[i])
  });
};

...

d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(data)

...
```

Comment: The values inside periodos should be the description on x, and the values inside reprovados the bar size, that's doing fine, just the names that are wrong. How can I put the periodos values on the x axis? By the way, thanks a lot man! You're a genius hahahah

Comment: now I understood it perfectly ... updated the demo ... thx for the compliment

Comment: Thansk, it's perfect now hahah How can I pass the json values from a file, not writing then on the variable?!

Comment: Updated ... the important line: `value: Number(json1.periodos[i])`